# I can't figure where the error is in this SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

When I run the query:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (p1, p2) VALUES ("test",0) WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE id=0);
```

it gives me `Error: near "WHERE": syntax error`

Where is the problem?

Comment: can you please explain your where clause ? and did you try to use a merge instead of insert

Comment: this may help you https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `VALUES` use `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (p1, p2) 
SELECT "test",0 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE id=0)
```

you don't need a `FROM` clause.
See the demo for [MySql](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/255kNwKEQEsAgvgjWftPdH/0) and for [SQLite](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/shNfWZ7jqSnS4ytvP3Z8rx/0).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SELECT` statement directly :

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (p1, p2)  
      SELECT DISTINCT "test", 0
      FROM Table1 
      WHERE id = 0;
```

Comment: This could insert multiple rows, if multiple rows match in `Table1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT` if you want `EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (p1, p2) 
    SELECT p1, p2
    FROM (SELECT 'test' as p1, 0 as p2) x
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.id = x.p2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to insert those values in Table2 only when you have an id=0 in Table1 why don't you use IF?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE id=0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table2 (p1, p2) VALUES ("test",0);
END
```